# software question about my apple ID

Tags: iphone, apple-id, password, software, ios

I downloaded the IOS8 and all of the sudden my iphone5 needed restoring and i lost all of my data!!!! Now that i can turn it on its like a brand new phone but my problem is that i cant restore my icloud OR my itunes account! i tried logging in my account but it says that my ID or password are wrong. I requested them to send me an email but i didnt receive anything until now. Someone please help me!!!!!!!!!!!! someone please tell me whats going on with my software

Answer (score 1):

Have you been backing up your iPhone?  If so, you can do the following to restore the backups:

- Go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> "Erase All Content and Settings"
- It will ask if your sure, you are.
- When the phone resets, it will ask if you would like to set this up as a new phone or restore from backup... tell it you want to restore.
- it will ask if it's an iCloud or iTunes based backup, give the correct answer.
- Wait until the restore is complete.

Note that if you're doing this from iCloud, you'll need to be WiFi connected for quite some time for the restore to complete.

If you have NOT been syncing/backing up your iPhone, you may be out of luck :-(

Alternatively, if this is really a question about how to recover your AppleID & Password, [you'll need to follow these steps](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5787) on Apple's website.